# send inline button in telegram bot in shell

Tags: bash, curl, button, telegram, telegram-bot

i have an array example:

`array=('google:https://google.com' 'instagram:https://Instagram.com')`

if user send `/start` in the bot send this inline button:

[google] with google.com link

[Instagram] with Instagram.com link

And they are above each other

i want a command like:

```
for button in "${array[@]}"; do
curl -s "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$id&button_text=$(echo $button | cut -d ':' -f1)&link=$(echo $button | cut -d ':' -f2)"
done
```

Comment: what is the question/issue? does your code run? do you get and error (and if so what is the error?)? does the code generate the wrong output (and if so what is the 'wrong' output)? please update the question with these details

Comment: It seems you need an [associative array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)

Comment: The `for` loop will execute both of the API calls. I think you may want to use a `case` statement to conditionally execute only one of the API calls based on the user's input